# Is there a physical intuition behind the disentanglement of Werner states and the sudden death of entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, open-quantum-systems

It [is possible to write two-qubit Werner states](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.07653.pdf) in terms of a mixture between a Bell state and the maximally mixed state:

\begin{equation}
\rho_W = \lambda |\Psi_-\rangle \langle\Psi_-| + \frac{1-\lambda}{4}{\bf 1}.
\end{equation}

Where $0 \leqslant \lambda \leqslant 1$ and $|\Psi_-\rangle = (|01\rangle-|10\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$.

It can also be shown that this state is entangled for $\lambda>1/3$ and separable otherwise. In the same spirit, the Werner state (and [a wider class of other physical states](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0404161)) are useful to illustrate the following physical scenario: they have been shown to disentangle in finite time under spontaneous emission/dissipation and [other type of setups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0602196.pdf), a phenomenon which is called sudden death of entanglement (SDE). This can be shown very easily through [the concurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrence_(quantum_computing)) $C(\rho_W)$ of two-qubit states, for example.

My question is: the mathematical justification is clear enough, but is there any physical intuition, e.g. geometrical, as why we observe this "sudden" change in the state behavior. While it is true that the concurrence $C(\rho_W)$ is continuous, so it is not quite sudden in this sense, it does not seem obvious to me as to why (i) the parametrization $\lambda$ determines the separability of the Werner states and (ii) why we observe a very different behavior between entanglement and coherence in the SDE scenario. A scenario where the concurrence decays in a similar fashion to the coherence, i.e. exponentially (but never reaches zero), would sound much more natural to me.

Is there a connection with any other concepts, relevant physical quantities, or recent works which elucidate these questions?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: There is no sudden change in the behavior. The entanglement gets smaller and smaller and at some point it is zero. Nothing suddenly changing. It would be far less intuitive if the state would stay entangled for all times. Note that the concurrence involves a "max", which gives exactly this type of behavior.